# editing (xarray) object in a function

Tags: function, python-xarray

I'm trying to assign extra variables to an existing dataset "ds" using a function which takes the dataset as argument and should return the adjusted dataset as well:

```
def Assign_Variable(dataset):
    dataset = dataset.assign(new_var = dataset.x + dataset.y)
    #(and some more manipulations)
    return dataset
```

and then use this function to loop through some datasets to manipulate them:

```
for dataset in [ds]:
    dataset = Assign_Variable(dataset)
```

Yet, if I now check my dataset ds, the function is not doing anything.

How can I adjust my datasets in a function, and return them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be done by treating the dataset like a dictionary (e.g. dataset[new_var] = ...)

As an example I have some code that calculates windspeed from two wind components u and v and saves the output windspeed (ws) in the existing dataset (ds):

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

def windspeed(dataset):
    dataset['ws'] = np.sqrt(dataset['u']**2 + dataset['v']**2)
    return dataset


# Create sample data
lon = np.arange(129.4, 153.75+0.05, 0.25)
lat = np.arange(-43.75, -10.1+0.05, 0.25)
data = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))
ds   = xr.Dataset({"u": (["lat", "lon"], data), "v": (["lat", "lon"], data)}, coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})

# Calc wind speed
ds = windspeed(ds)

# Print output
print(ds)
```

The output dataset now contains the three variables u, v and ws.