# How can I use dimensions and data in xarray to create a new array of data?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I'm running into issues with DataSets in [Xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org). I'd like to apply a function to data and coordinates already in the dataset to compute a new set of data (essentially, *w* = *f*(*x, y, z*), where *x*, *y*, and *z* are floats).

There are a series of functions that need to be applied, and the dimensions of the resulting array need to expand when a new variable is pulled in. So f(x) should be a 1D array, g(f(x), y) should be 2D, and h(g(f(x), y), z) should be a 3D array created from the previous 2D array. I'm able to use `np.outer` to force the 1D -> 2D transformation, but I'm having trouble with the 2D -> 3D conversion. Given the amount of trouble I'm having, I suspect I'm coming at the problem from the wrong direction.

Below is a snippet of some of the code. Can someone help me understand the correct way to approach this problem from a NumPy/Xarray standpoint (I'm *really* trying avoid dropping to a loop for this work…)

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        "abs": (("x"), np.ones((200)))
    },
    coords={
        "x": np.linspace(1.5,1.55,200),
        "y": np.arange(5e5),
        "z": np.arange(125)
    }
)

def intensity_decay(da):
    "Return decay curve (exponential decay)."
    init_power = 1e5
    decay = init_power * np.exp(
        -1 * np.outer(da.abs, da.y * 10 ** (-7))
        )
    decay[decay < 1e-3] = 0
    return decay

data["depth_decay"] = (["x", "y"], intensity_decay(data))

def radial_decay(da):
    "Return radial decay curve."
    return np.outer(da.depth_decay, np.exp(-da.z))

radial_decay(data.isel(x=[1, 4, 10])).shape
```

As you can see, the `radial_decay` function doesn't broadcast into the *z* dimension. It seems like Xarray should support this type of operation, but I don't know how to approach the problem, or even where to start in the documentation. I currently have two datasets to which I'd like to apply these function, so I could do it by hand, but I want to make a framework I can use on future data as well.

Comment: xarray can automatically broadcast named dimensions so I think this should not be too complicated. But as far as I see there is currently something wrong with your initial assignment of the dimensions. Your example throws an error because you pass a 2-dimensional array as the data argument for `abs` but specify only a single dimension (`x`). Also the lengthes of the `x` dimension do not match between `abs` and the `x`-coordinate. So what are the dimensions of the `abs`variable?

Comment: For more info on broadcasting in xarray and examples see [the documentation](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name) or [this tutorial](https://xarray-contrib.github.io/xarray-tutorial/online-tutorial-series/03_computation.html#Broadcasting:).

Comment: You’re right, I grabbed a sample array and forgot to change the data. `abs` should be a 1d array of values, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit and using the function structure found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65332923/2216427), I was able to come up with an output of the right shape.

By defining the `radial_decay` function as follows, I can get an output array with three dimensions.

```py
def radial_decay(da):
    "Return radial decay curve."
    da["radial_decay"] = (["x", "y", "z"], da.depth_decay * np.exp(-da.z))
    return da
```

With this structure, the output of `radial_decay(data.isel(x=[1, 4, 10])).radial_decay.shape` is `(3, 500000, 125)`, rather than `(1500000,125)` using the function defined in the original question.

While this seems to work (I still need to verify that the *values* are correct), I'd like to know if there are any other (better?) methods to achieve this goal, particularly if there are better ways with *just* NumPy to do this (in case I don't have access to Xarray for some reason in the future).